# Use Pandas dataframe to add lag feature from MultiIindex Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a MultiIndex Series (3 indices) that looks like this:

```
Week   ID_1    ID_2
3       26     1182            39.0
               4767            42.0
               31393           20.0
               31690           42.0
               32962            3.0
....................................
```

I also have a dataframe `df` which contains all the columns (and more) used for indices in the Series above, and I want to create a new column in my dataframe `df` that contains the value matching the `ID_1` and `ID_2` and the `Week - 2` from the Series.

For example, for the row in dataframe that has `ID_1 = 26`, `ID_2 = 1182` and `Week = 3`, I want to match the value in the Series indexed by `ID_1 = 26`, `ID_2 = 1182` and `Week = 1` (3-2) and put it on that row in a new column. Further, my Series might not necessarily have the value required by the dataframe, in which case I'd like to just have 0.

Right now, I am trying to do this by using:

```
[multiindex_series.get((x[1].get('week', 2) - 2, x[1].get('ID_1', 0), x[1].get('ID_2', 0))) for x in df.iterrows()]
```

This however is very slow and memory hungry and I was wondering what are some better ways to do this.

FWIW, the Series was created using

```
saved_groupby = df.groupby(['Week', 'ID_1', 'ID_2'])['Target'].median()
```

and I'm willing to do it a different way if better paths exist to create what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the `Week` by 2:

```
saved_groupby = df.groupby(['Week', 'ID_1', 'ID_2'])['Target'].median()
saved_groupby = saved_groupby.reset_index()
saved_groupby['Week'] = saved_groupby['Week'] + 2
```

and then merge `df` with `saved_groupby`:

```
result = pd.merge(df, saved_groupby, on=['Week', 'ID_1', 'ID_2'], how='left')
```

This will augment `df` with the target median from 2 weeks ago.
To make the median (target) `saved_groupby` column 0 when there is no match, use `fillna` to change NaNs to 0:

```
result['Median'] = result['Median'].fillna(0)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(20,5)), 
                  columns=['Week', 'ID_1', 'ID_2', 'Target', 'Foo'])

saved_groupby = df.groupby(['Week', 'ID_1', 'ID_2'])['Target'].median()
saved_groupby = saved_groupby.reset_index()
saved_groupby['Week'] = saved_groupby['Week'] + 2
saved_groupby = saved_groupby.rename(columns={'Target':'Median'})

result = pd.merge(df, saved_groupby, on=['Week', 'ID_1', 'ID_2'], how='left')
result['Median'] = result['Median'].fillna(0)
print(result)
```

yields

```
    Week  ID_1  ID_2  Target  Foo  Median
0      3     2     3       4    2     0.0
1      3     3     0       3    4     0.0
2      4     3     0       1    2     0.0
3      3     4     1       1    1     0.0
4      2     4     2       0    3     2.0
5      1     0     1       4    4     0.0
6      2     3     4       0    0     0.0
7      4     0     0       2    3     0.0
8      3     4     3       2    2     0.0
9      2     2     4       0    1     0.0
10     2     0     4       4    2     0.0
11     1     1     3       0    0     0.0
12     0     1     0       2    0     0.0
13     4     0     4       0    3     4.0
14     1     2     1       3    1     0.0
15     3     0     1       3    4     2.0
16     0     4     2       2    4     0.0
17     1     1     4       4    2     0.0
18     4     1     0       3    0     0.0
19     1     0     1       0    0     0.0
```

Comment: Brilliant, haven't even considered resetting the index, thanks! I think that to match my problem I should **add** 2 to the week though, no? Otherwise, the dataframe will contain the median target of future weeks I believe.

Comment: Right, if you want to augment the original DataFrame with the median target from 2 weeks ago, then use  `saved_groupby['Week'] = saved_groupby['Week'] + 2`.